# How to return this format this JSON into an array of strings

Tags: c#, json, linq, javascriptserializer

I am executing a  linq query which gets me all the records from a table:

```
var data = _context.People.ToList(); //_context is my DataContext.
```

The above returns the the value:

`{
        "name": "john",
        "age": "30"
    },
    {
        "name": "jane",
        "age": "31"
    }`

but according to [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/), this is invalid and I need to have it be returned as:

`[{
        "name": "john",
        "age": "30"
    },
    {
        "name": "jane",
        "age": "31"
    }]`

How can I do this?

```
 viewData.xldata = [];
         $.each(data, function(i, row) {
            var strRow = JSON.stringify(row);
            viewData.xldata.push(strRow);});
```

Deserialize using `JavaScriptSerializer:

```
var people = jss.Deserialize<List<People>>(args["xldata"]);
```

Comment: How are you converting `List` to json?

Comment: @BhushanFirake - I have a script where I loop through each row and stringify it. I updated the post.

Comment: use `JSON.stringify(data);` in your code directly, no need of loop

Comment: Oh. I thought you were trying to generate a json-valid string in server side code, not javascript, oops.

Comment: @BhushanFirake - I did that and that put the `[]` around the string, but now I get the error message: `Type 'JsonDictionaryObject' is not supported for deserialization of an array.` in the line: `  public JsonDictionaryObject(string JsonString) : base(jss.Deserialize<JsonDictionaryObject>(JsonString)) { }`

Comment: @Xaisoft You don't need to put anything around the string returned by `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: @BhushanFirake - If I take away `JSON.stringify(data)`, my JSON looks like : `"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"` and it says `Invalid JSON primititive:object`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    List<People> data= _context.People.ToList();

   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer objSerializer = default(System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer);
   objSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

    return objSerializer.Serialize(data);
```